# Translating the phrase "not nearly enough"

Tags: traducción, modismos, inglés

I'd like the translate the phrase "not nearly enough" into Spanish.  The phrase is used in the sense of something not being even close to the level you are expecting, or often, are hoping for.

The target level (that has not been reached) is not usually known, is not typically a definite value, and may have the qualities of infinity.

For instance, if someone were carrying $150,000, and they were asked how much money they were carrying, and that person replied "Not nearly enough.", what's implied is that person would like to have a mountain full of cash.

Answer (score 10):

This makes me think on the idiom "**Ni de lejos**". This means "not even close", which in some cases can match what you are mentioning.

See an example:

> -¿Has ganado la lotería?
>   <sub>Did you win the lottery?</sub>
>
> -Ni de lejos: ¡no acerté ni un número!
>   <sub>Not even close: I didn't match any number!</sub>

Answer (score 7):

I would probably go with:

> No lo suficiente.

It can be used the same way as your expression:

> -How much money do you make?
>
> -Not nearly enough.

Would get translated as:

> -Cuanto dinero ganas?
>
> -No lo suficiente.

Comment: `No lo suficiente` just means `not enough`. I think a closer translation would be `Ni de lejos lo suficiente`.

Comment: No lo suficiente seems about right. Although if you want to stress it even more, I'd go with "ni siquiera lo suficiente". In the OP'S example it'd be something like "no gano ni siquiera lo suficiente". However, my first choice would be "no lo suficiente".

Answer (score 2):

In the context given, I would favor `menos de lo que me gustaría`.

Again, given your example, you ask that guy who would like to have mountains of money how much he is carrying or has

> Menos de lo que me gustaría (I know I have a huge lot, which is enough for almost anything, but I would like even more).

Other examples.

> A: Cuanto te van a pagar en el trabajo nuevo?
>
> B: Menos de lo que me gustaría. No está mal, pero creo que podría haber negociado más
>
> A: Cuantas firmas hemos recogido?
>
> B: Menos de las que nos gustaría. Hay bastantes, pero podrían haber sido más.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Argentina and here we speak Spanish.
The correct translations following the context, are several:

> Ni de cerca, lo suficiente (family-friendly way).
>
> No lo suficiente (formal speaking way).

Answer (score 1):

Can work this: "**para nada suficiente**". However it's a bit complicated logic because would have to use a double negative:

> -¿Te parece bien $150.000?
>
> -No es para nada suficiente.